# How to read multiple integers in multiple lines when the number of integers in each line is unknown

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

EDIT: This is the input: 
1st number is m, followed by m numbers. Next entry is n followed by n lines, each with varying and unknown number of elements.

5

1 2 3 4 5

3

1 2 3 4 5 6

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4

How can I read this input in Java using the scanner class? `nextInt` doesn't seem to take the next line character into account.
One way is to take the whole line as input and get the integers from it but am looking for something faster.

My code works for the following constraints:
1 ≤ M ≤ 10 
1 ≤ N ≤ 100 
The number of elements in the n lines ranges between 1 and 100

but times out for the following(takes more than 3s):
1 ≤ M ≤ 100
1 ≤ N ≤ 9 x 103
The number of elements in the n lines ranges between 1 and 1000

Here's what am doing:

```
public static void main(String[] str) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> qualities = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int m = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        qualities.add(in.nextInt());

    int n = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
        HashSet<Integer> qua = new HashSet<Integer>();
        String[] strng = in.nextLine().split(" ");

        for(String x: strng)
            qua.add(Integer.parseInt(x));
            solve(qua);
    }
    System.out.print(count);
}
```

Just wanted to know if there is a way I can avoid using in.nextLine() while reading the line with multiple integers and just use in.nextInt() instead. 
The number of integers in each line varies and is unknown.

Comment: The input is like: 1 2 3 4 5 6 *next line* 1 2 3 4 5 *next line* 1 2 3 4

Comment: "but am looking for something faster" - that suggests you've got something that works, but it's too slow. Please post your working code, along with observed timing and performance requirements.

Comment: Is the whole thing a string? Just remove \n from it and put it into the scanner, and be on your way.

Comment: You still haven't explained your claim that you need something faster. What are your performance criteria, and how does the current code behave? I'd expect IO to dominate this anyway...

Answer (score 2):

> How can I read this input in Java using the scanner class?

To detect new line with `Scanner`, you need to have 2 things.

1)Grasp the first line say L.

2)Feed L into a `new Scanner`and get your `Int`s.

Something like:

```
  Scanner scan=new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));  

        while(scan.hasNext())
       {
          String s=scan.nextLine();
          Scanner inscan=new Scanner(s);
             while(inscan.hasNext())
                  System.out.print(" "+inscan.nextInt());
          System.out.println("");
          inscan.close();

        }
         scan.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    String contents = 
        "3\n" + 
        "1 2 3 4 5 6\n" +
        "1 2 3 4 5\n" +
        "1 2 3 4\n";

    int[][] result = null;

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(contents))) {
        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            if (result == null)
                result = new int[count = Integer.parseInt(line)][];
            else if (i < count)
                result[i++] = Stream.of(line.split(" "))
                    .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
                    .toArray();
            else
                break;
    }
    for (int[] line : result)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line));
    // result:
    // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Scanner you don't need to do anything other than use it. This code works for both a string input and direct input from the system input. As you can see it is a simple use of Scanner, the only change is to decide which way you want to instantiate the scanner, i.e. to select either a String or System.input source.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("\nInput some numbers (end by typing a non number)"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        String contents = 
                        "1 2 3 4 5\n" + 
                        "1 3 5 7 9\n" +
                        "5 4 3 2 1\n" +
                        "100 33 -146\n";

        // scanner form string
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(contents);
        // scanner from system input
//      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<Integer> li = new LinkedList<>();

        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                Integer i = sc.nextInt();
                li.add(new Integer(i));
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                break;
            }
            catch(NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                break;
            }

        }

        Integer sum = 0;

        for (Integer i : li)
        {
            sum += i;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("sum = ").append(sum); //$NON-NLS-1$
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        sc.close();
    }
```

running with the Scanner linked to the String or the System input produces the same result

```
42
```

No special handling of \n is required due to the whitespace rules employe din java.

EDIT:
The InputMismatchException exception is thrown when the System.input source is used and you enter a non number, like an X. The NoSuchElementException exception is thrown when the source is a String and the input is exhausted.

This is just an example, you woul dhave to handle end of System.input better for production code.